# How to insert a figure in tikzposter with labels and captions?

Tags: templates, tikzposter, a0poster

I am writing a poster of a0 size with the help of standard [tikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter) poster tempelate.

Due to some reasons, the standard latex format as given below wouldn't work.

```
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example_picture.png}}
    \caption[]{This is an example picture}
    \label{example_picture}
    \end{figure}
```

But according to the tikzposter Manual, one can use something called \tikzpicture. 
How to do that ? 
Can anyone help ?

Gunn

Comment: Could you make your question more specific, and maybe give us an example (MWE)?

Comment: While on most SE sites, the standard is to close unclear question and reopen them when they get better, remember that we prefer not to close them at all and leave the author a day or so to improve the question. Therefore this should not be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for, but I am not sure about the label though. You can caption it like this:

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[CAPTION HERE]
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example_picture.png}
\end{tikzfigure}
```

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on @msakya's answer, this illustrates the idiosyncracies:

```
\setcounter{figurecounter}{98}
\begin{tikzfigure}[CAPTION HERE\label{here}]
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example_picture.png}
\end{tikzfigure}
Figure \ref{here} ain't one.
```

Comment: This code is incorrect, it won't work. According to [the documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter/tikzposter.pdf), `\label{here}` should be inside the figure block.